# Strange behaviour of StaggeredGridLayout when updating data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am updating the list in the adapter retrieved from viewmodel. My adapter inherits from ListAdapter and also implements DiffUtil.ItemCallback

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val adapter = NotesAdapter { note ->
        navigateToDetail(note.id)
    }
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true)

    val layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
    layoutManager.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS

    binding.recycler.adapter = adapter
    binding.recycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
    binding.recycler.addItemDecoration(SpacesItemDecoration(DEFAULT_NOTE_CARD_SPACING))
    
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            viewModel.notesList.onEach { notes ->
                adapter.submitList(notes)
            }.launchIn(this)

            viewModel.foldersList.onEach { folders ->
                folders.forEach { folder ->
                    binding.chipGroup.addChip(folder.id.toInt(), folder.name)
                }
            }.launchIn(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Why can this strange error occur when updating a list in StaggeredGridLayout?

https://imgur.com/a/uwljlrC

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using a `ListAdapter` with `DiffUtils`. However, the reason why AsyncDiffer behaves so strangely when updating data is not clear to me.